# How do I get the @a player selector to work with the /effect command on a Bukkit server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

I'm trying to use the `/effect` command to play around with giving everyone on my server a jump boost. The problem is that I can't seem to get the `@a` player selector to work. Is this because I'm using Bukkit and not the vanilla server?

I typed this command into the server console:

```
effect @a 8 60 5
```

and I got this message:

```
Player, @a, not found
```

I'm running Bukkit 1.7.2-R0.3 (#2975) with no plugins.

Comment: I thought `/effect` was added to the latest Bukkit version.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to use `@a` in the console. Although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: The thing is, I've seen YouTube videos where people use it (1:25 at [sethbling: UHC S13E01](http://youtu.be/mHJswYOf3c8?t=1m25s)). So what's going on in that video?

Comment: Resolution: In Bukkit, player selectors do not work in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling players by starting with @ (for example, @a) won't work with bukkit. This isn't just the /effect command.

Comment: So is there a work around?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: Do they work at all? What about in a command block?

Comment: I don't *think* they work with command blocks but they might, I haven't tried it in a while. I'm about 95% sure they don't.

Comment: @stephenwade I just tested it, they do.

Comment: I think `*` will do...?